# Can I download and install Blender outside of Steam?

Tags: installation

I currently have a falling out with Steam over a customer service issue. As a Blender subscriber (gold member), can I download and install outside of the Steam universe?

Comment: Iam not sure if I understand your questions, but do you ask if you can download blender somewhere else than on Steam? Yes, for example on official site blender.com

Comment: https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: Iam not sure if I understand your questions, but do you ask if you can download blender somewhere else than on Steam? Yes, for example on official site blender.com – Fowl 2 days ago. Yes. This is what I'm asking. Thank You.